# At what point in Controller execution is TempData populated

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a base class for my controllers. In the constructor of the base class I was trying to populate a ViewBag property from TempData. However it seems that TempData is not populated at that point, nor is it in the OnBeginExecute method.

I need to populate this ViewBag property in the base class, as all controllers need the same variable (it's a redirection message).

Which override of Controller in my base class can I use to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [`BeginExecuteCore`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.asynccontroller.beginexecutecore%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
protected override IAsyncResult BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, object state)
{
    // TempData is not populated here
    var result = base.BeginExecuteCore(callback, state);
    // TempData is populated here

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

TempData as well as any HttpContext related stuff is not available in the controller constructor. You can use them starting from the [Initialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.initialize.aspx) method. So if you need to populate them in a global manner for a controller either override this method or write a custom action filter and decorate your controller with it:

```
public class HomeController: Controller
{
    protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(requestContext);
        // now you can access the HttpContext
    }

    ...
}
```